# Why am I getting a System.InvalidCastException for my own types?

Tags: c#, generics

My method `ImplementingInterface` below, gets all of my own classes implementing my custom interface, `IInstaller`.

```
private static IEnumerable<Assembly> MyAssemblies
{
    get { return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x=>x.GetName().Name.StartsWith("ProjectPrefix", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); }
}

public static IEnumerable<TInterface> ImplementingInterface<TInterface>() where TInterface : class
{
    var interfaceType = typeof(TInterface);

    if (!interfaceType.IsInterface)
        throw new Exception(interfaceType.Name + " is not an interface.");

    var types = new List<Type>();

    foreach (var assembly in MyAssemblies) 
    {
        types.AddRange(assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.ImplementedInterfaces.Any(inter => inter == interfaceType)));
    }

    var expectedTypes = types.ToList();
    var interfaces = expectedTypes.Cast<TInterface>().ToList(); // Error occurs.

}
```

But when it hit the line marked below with `error occurs` it throws the following error:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'ProjectPrefix.IInstaller'.`

`expectedTypes` has 3 classes that all implement `IInstaller`, why is it throwing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're searching for types - so your result is an `IEnumerable<Type>`. Those `Type` objects don't implement your interface - *instances* of the types would implement the interface.

So your code is trying to do something a little like:

```
IInstaller installer = typeof(SomeInstaller);
```

instead of:

```
IInstaller installer = new SomeInstaller();
```

If you want to be able to cast to the interface, you'll need to create instances of the types. If you're trying to dynamically create instances, and if they all have a public parameterless constructor, you could just use `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
// Get rid of the AddRange call... there's no point in that, or calling
// ToList() on something that's already a list. Use LINQ to its fullest :)
return assembly.DefinedTypes
               .Where(t => t.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(interfaceType))
               .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t))
               .Cast<TInterface>()
               .ToList();
```

Or using [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
return assembly.DefinedTypes
               .Where(t => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
               .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t))
               .Cast<TInterface>()
               .ToList();
```

Comment: ....or check whether the type implements the interface using one of the methods of the type. THere is one that you can ask whether an instance would implement an interface.

Comment: @TomTom: Yes, I was getting there. But I wanted to correct the most important part of the OP's code first :)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks what an idiot I am, only one thing it picks up IInstaller as one of the types as well, so the `where` should become: `.Where(t=> interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)`

Comment: @shenku: Or you could detect if the type is a concrete class, which would let you find all the implementations which *didn't* have parameterless constructors but should do.